# How to attach the VSCode debugger to the Brave browser?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, brave

When I open my web application in the `Chrome` browser I can attach the `VSCode` debugger to it.

The debugger configuration is:

```
{
    "name": "Attach to Chrome",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 9222,
    "url": "http://localhost:4200/*",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
},
```

But when I open the web application in the Brave browser I cannot attach the `VSCode` debugger.

The web application is an `Angular` one opened at `http://localhost:4200/users`

I'm running:

```
Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102 (Build officiel) (64 bits)
Brave Version 0.56.12 Chromium: 70.0.3538.77 (Build officiel) (64 bits)
VSCode Version 1.23.0
```

on a `Lubuntu 16.04` box.

Is the `Brave` browser not yet ready for debugging ? Or is there some port restriction I should remove ? I have put the shiled down for this web application. But `VSCode` still does not attach to it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A little late but....
get `brave-dev` following [this](https://brave.com/download-dev/)

then add to your `launch.json` a `"runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/brave"` entry and change the path that suits you.

rest of the settings can be default

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on windows when using the correct path to brave.exe. It's the same issue with the regular brave and the dev version

Comment: Works for me (Windows 10)

Comment: You need to launch Brave with the following option : `--remote-debugging-port=9222` (see my answer)

Answer (score 38):

**For MacOS users**

I was able to connect to create a configuration in `launch.json` so that the Brave browser launches on MacOS. I appended the `"userData": true` property because I was getting an error. I figured that out by looking at this page. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Brave",
    "runtimeExecutable": "/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser",
    "userDataDir": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Comment: Just the "runtimeExecutable" was enough for me,

Comment: did somebody manage to get the user profile loaded?

Comment: @daydr3amer yes. You have to run brave with `--profile-directory=<profile_name>`.

Comment: @Danny_DD where did you specify that flag?  If I add it to the end of the `runtimeExecutable` value Brave fails to launch altogether

Answer (score 12):

*The DEV version of Brave is not necessary.*

In your Brave browser, under "chrome://settings/privacy", enable the "Remote debugging" option.

Restart your browser.

If not done yet, add to your launch.json file this (adjust your path if it is not the same)

`"runtimeExecutable": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe",`

Comment: I can't find such a "remote debugging" option - maybe this is available only in the dev build of Brave?

Comment: You cant find it because they removed it in August of 2020 re: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/9715

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the other answers, you need to add a "runtimeExecutable" field in the launch.json file of your project that will point to the executable of Brave Browser.

### ... but ...

**You also need to launch the browser with the following option : `--remote-debugging-port=9222`**

You have 2 ways to do it :

1. Launching Brave with the option (Windows : Right click the Brave shortcut, and select properties, and in the "target" field, append `--remote-debugging-port=9222`, MacOS / linux : execute `<path to brave>/brave --remote-debugging-port=9222`) (reminder : don't forget to relaunch Brave)
2. Following [Cornelius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7483211/cornelius-roemer) suggestion, you can simply add the following to your `launch.json` :

```json
"runtimeArgs": [ "--remote-debugging-port=9222" ]
```

This second option applies ONLY if you have the `request: "launch"` option, not the `request: "attach"` one, and if you want to use the "lauch" option, it will open another Brave window, not a new tab. So you'll probably want to use the first method in the long run.

Comment: Could this remote debugging port option be added through "runtimeArgs" in the launch.json?

Comment: Well, it actually works ! I've edited my message, BUT, there is a catch : it works with `request: "launch"` only. For the `request: "attach"` you still need to launch Brave with the  option separately

Answer (score 4):

For those that need to see full code context, here is my complete launch.json file. The second item in the `"configurations"` array causes brave's dev browser to open for debugging ([you can download the Brave dev browser here](https://brave.com/download-dev/))

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Brave",
            "runtimeExecutable": "C:/Program Files (x86)/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser-Dev/Application/brave.exe",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Brave install with APT package manager on Running Ubuntu 20.04

Add this line to the standard launch.json generated for chrome:

```
"runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/brave-browser"
```

Here is how the whole launch.json looks. If you want to copy this just make sure `file` points to the right location.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Open index.html",
            "file": "/home/my-user/myDirectory/index.html",
            "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/brave-browser"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps to follow:

1. Open vs code.
2. wait for sec. bez it take time to open vs code
3. see left side Search icon.
4. click on it and type Setting.
5. see down  click on Open setting.
6. Browser.

[image: check this one]

```
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "brave
```

or try this:

```
.vscode\settings.json:
  {
  "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "brave"
 }
```

Comment: Works on Windows 10, thanks !

Comment: Thanks! Works like wonders